# How can I schedule a stored process in SAS DI Studio?

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide, sas-dis

I would like to use Enterprise Guide as a development environment for creating a SAS job (Base SAS code only), but I then need to use DI Studio to schedule that job to run at a particular time.

I want to use EG for developing the job because I believe it is a better development environment (program editor etc.) than DI.

I also want the job to exist as a stored process so that users can run it *outside* the schedule if necessary.

Can I create a simple DI Studio job that merely calls an existing stored process?

Answer (score 1):

Of course - there are many ways to achieve this.  One is to create a separate job (with 'user written code' component) and Stored Process,  both of which simply `%include` your Enterprise Guide program.

Another is to create your stored process using Enterprise Guide, and then in DI Studio (user written code) call the stored process directly using `proc stp` (see [documentation](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/stpug/62758/HTML/default/viewer.htm#stpugwhatsnew93.htm))

Yet another is to paste your EG code into DI Studio and 'deploy job as stored process' - documentation for that is [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etlug/65807/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p141qlfzqvlcqbn1taqjyase32b1.htm).

Oh, and to answer your 'headline' question - you don't schedule jobs in DI!  The deployed .sas code can be scheduled via Schedule Manager (SMC), the OS itself, or other third party tools (eg LSF).

Comment: +1 on using `%include` for both DI jobs and stored processes.  Keeps the .sas code out of metadata, and easily maintainable using any editor / IDE.